# Problems with Scrapy array items

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a little problem with scrapy crawling items. This is the output of the crawling but i would like another format.
I'd like to save the extracted data to a Posgresql database so i can't with this format.

```
{'desc': [u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N5010 / N5110\xa0',
          u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N7010 / N7110\ufeff - Li-ion 11.1V / 5200mAh',
          u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Toshiba A200 - Li-ion 10.8V / 5200mAh',
          u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP ProBook 4510S - Li-ion 10.8V / 5200mAh',
          u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP Compaq CQ45 / CQ50 / CQ60 - HP Pavilion DV4 / DV5 / DV6\ufeff\ufeff - Li-ion 10.8V / 5200mAh',
          u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP Compaq CQ42 / CQ62\ufeff - Li-ion 10.8V / 5200mAh'],
 'link': [u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/8442-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-dell-inspiron-n5010-n5110.html',
          u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/8443-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-dell-inspiron-n7010-n7110.html',
          u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/7735-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-toshiba-a200.html',
          u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/7729-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-hp-probook-4510s.html',
          u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/7726-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-hp-compaq-cq45-cq50-cq60-dv4-dv5-dv6.html',
          u'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/7725-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-hp-compaq-cq42-cq62.html'],
 'price': [u'69,900 DT',
           u'69,900 DT',
           u'69,900 DT',
           u'69,900 DT',
           u'69,900 DT',
           u'69,900 DT'],
 'title': [u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N5010 / N5110',
           u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N7010 / N7110',
           u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Toshiba A200',
           u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP ProBook 4510S',
           u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP Compaq CQ45 / CQ50 / CQ60 / DV4 / DV5 / DV6',
           u'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable HP Compaq CQ42 / CQ62']}
```

instead of this i would like to get the output like this:

```
{'desc':'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N5010 / N5110',
'link':'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/batterie-pour-pc-portable/7725-batterie-6-cellules-pour-pc-portable-hp-compaq-cq42-cq62.html'} ...

'price':'69,900 DT'
'title':'Batterie 6 Cellules Pour PC Portable Dell Inspiron N5010 / N5110'
```

My Spider code :

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from ecommerce.items import ArticleItem

class Tunisianet_Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tunisianet'
    start_urls = ('http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/',
    ) # urls from which the spider will start crawling
    rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{3}-\w+-\w+-\w+$']), callback='parse_Article_tunisianet'),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{3}-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+$']),     callback='parse_Article_tunisianet'),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{3}-\w+$']), callback='parse_Article_tunisianet'),
    # r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+' : regular expression for http://tunisianet.com.tn/220-telephone-    portable-tunisie
    ]
    def parse_Article_tunisianet(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = ArticleItem()
        # Extract title
        item['title'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['desc'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/p[1]/a/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_prix"]/div[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/h2/a/@href').extract()

    return item
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop on each `<ul class="clear" id="product_list"><li...>`

and for each list item:

- instantiate a new `ArticleItem`
- apply relative XPath selections

Something like:

```
def parse_Article_tunisianet(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    for li in hxs.select('//ul[@id="product_list"]/li'):
        item = ArticleItem()
        # Extract title
        item['title'] = li.select('.//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['desc'] = li.select('.//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/p[1]/a/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = li.select('.//*[@id="produit_liste_prix"]/div[1]/span/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = li.select('.//*[@id="produit_liste_texte"]/div/h2/a/@href').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: Paul, a bit of off-topic: checked out `parslepy` - this is really a great thing you've done - thank you. I guess I have a good use case for it :) +1 for the answer, of course.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Let me know how it goes with parslepy. Contributions welcome ;-)